# Problems mounting old Iomega NAS drive in unrealated Ubuntu environment

Tags: mount, lvm, mdadm, nas

I'm posting on the StackExchange Unix&Linux community board first, as it seams to be the most likely place for the type of answers I'm looking for. I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have spent the last two days off and on trying to access an old drive from an Iomega HMNHD CE (see here: [http://iomega.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:Home_Media_CE](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320183933/http://iomega.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:Home_Media_CE)), and from what I can confirm from the drive uses MD to create its 'raid' configuration (as per the boot log provided in the restoration guide). Additionally, I've tried to follow instructions from the original hacking guide ([http://iomega.nas-central.org/wiki/Root_access_enabling_(Home_Media_CE)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150316102306/http://iomega.nas-central.org/wiki/Root_access_enabling_(Home_Media_CE))), but what worked on my ancient PC way back when no longer works the same way. I'm now using a modern Ubuntu to try to do this. I would have originally been using probably something like Debian lenny.

The physical hard disk is in perfect working order. It is more that I'm extremely rusty and any unix/linux fu I had appears to have deserted me.

NOTE: I am not trying to 'restore' the drive, I am trying to gain access to the data partition on the drive using a PC to which the drive has been attached via USB. The drive is working and correctly attached, the issue is with whatever way the device/partitions/volumes need to be mounted.

The issue is that although I can get the drive to be seen, the partitions do not mount. I'm not interested at this stage particularly in the first partition (sdc1) as this contains two volumes, one is the initramfs image to boot the device, and a series of nested app and system related volumes - if worst came to worst and I wanted this data, it can be recreated from the original 'firmware' images. The second partition (sdc2) however contains the data volume, and it is there that all the SMB shares are located. It is this data I am trying to retrieve.

*This has been revised and tidied up to reflect advice already received*

```
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# hdparm -I /dev/sdc
    /dev/sdc:
    SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    
    ATA device, with non-removable media
    Standards:
                Likely used: 1
    Configuration:
                Logical         max     current
                cylinders       0       0
                heads           0       0
                sectors/track   0       0
                --
                Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
                device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
                device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes
                cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Capabilities:
                IORDY not likely
                Cannot perform double-word IO
                R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
                DMA: not supported
                PIO: pio0

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
    /dev/sdc:
       MBR Magic : aa55
    Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
    unused devices: <none>
    
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# cat /proc/partitions
    major minor  #blocks  name
    
       1        0      65536 ram0

       ... SNIP ...

       8        0     399176 sda
       8       16    2097156 sdb
       8       32 1953514584 sdc
       8       33   20971520 sdc1
       8       34  955758261 sdc2
     252        0   20971520 dm-0

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# pvscan --cache
    pvscan[394] PV /dev/sdc2 online.

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# vgscan --mknodes
    Found volume group "46b8de_vg11" using metadata type lvm2

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# lvs
    LV         VG          Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
    lv15807ccd 46b8de_vg11 -wi-a----- 911.48g

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# pvs
    PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
    /dev/sdc2  46b8de_vg11 lvm2 a--  911.48g     0

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# vgs
    VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
    46b8de_vg11   1   1   0 wz--n- 911.48g     0

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# vgchange -ay -vvv
    ... SEE COMMENTS FOR ADDITIONAL RESULTS ...

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# lvscan
    ACTIVE            '/dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd' [911.48 GiB] inherit

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# lsblk
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda      8:0    0 389.8M  1 disk
    sdb      8:16   0     2G  0 disk [SWAP]
    sdc      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
    ├─sdc1   8:49   0    20G  0 part
    └─sdc2   8:50   0 911.5G  0 part
    sdd      8:32   0   256G  0 disk

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# lvmdiskscan
    
    ... SNIP (RAM) ...
    
    /dev/sda   [     389.82 MiB]
    /dev/sdb   [       2.00 GiB]
    /dev/sdc1  [      20.00 GiB]
    /dev/sdc2  [     911.48 GiB] LVM physical volume
    /dev/sdd   [     256.00 GiB]
    
    3 disks
    17 partitions
    0 LVM physical volume whole disks
    1 LVM physical volume

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# parted -l
    Warning: Unable to open /dev/sda read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sda has been opened read-only.
    Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sda: 409MB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: loop
    Disk Flags:

    Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
    1      0.00B  409MB  409MB  ext2


    Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdb: 2147MB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: loop
    Disk Flags:

    Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
    1      0.00B  2147MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)


    Model: ASMedia asm1153e (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: gpt
    Disk Flags:

    Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
    1      33.6MB  21.5GB  21.5GB               primary  raid
    2      21.5GB  1000GB  979GB                primary  msftdata
    
    Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdd: 275GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: loop
    Disk Flags:

    Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
    1      0.00B  275GB  275GB  ext4

 
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# more /etc/lvm/backup/46b8de_vg
    # Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.07(2) (2019-11-30): Mon Jan 22 18:19:57 2024

    contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
    version = 1

    description = "Created *after* executing 'vgs'"

    creation_host = "LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH"       # Linux LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64
    creation_time = 1705947597      # Mon Jan 22 18:19:57 2024

    46b8de_vg {
         id = "1ooII8-zoas-M8bF-BekN-h3qG-Vags-RYLTD5"
         seqno = 2
         format = "lvm2"                 # informational
         status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
         flags = []
         extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
         max_lv = 0
         max_pv = 0
         metadata_copies = 0

         physical_volumes {

                 pv0 {
                         id = "2NlG4k-xIZl-NgIz-0glj-DMqD-IYVB-AuiwWF"
                         device = "/dev/mapper/sdc2"     # Hint only

                         status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                         flags = []
                         dev_size = 1911516416   # 911.482 Gigabytes
                         pe_start = 384
                         pe_count = 233339       # 911.48 Gigabytes
                 }
         }

         logical_volumes {

                 lv15807ccd {
                         id = "m4WEST-MOJL-scOg-vlcG-s9uZ-nelQ-0oBvYd"
                         status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                         flags = []
                         segment_count = 1

                         segment1 {
                                 start_extent = 0
                                 extent_count = 233339   # 911.48 Gigabytes

                                 type = "striped"
                                 stripe_count = 1        # linear

                                 stripes = [
                                         "pv0", 0
                                 ]
                         }
                 }
         }

    }

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# ls /dev/
    autofs           fuse          loop1   ptmx   ram4    sdd    tty11  tty23  tty35  tty47  tty59  urandom
    block            hvc0          loop2   ptp0   ram5    sg0     tty12  tty24  tty36  tty48  tty6   vcs
    bsg              hvc1          loop3   pts    ram6    sg1     tty13  tty25  tty37  tty49  tty60  vcs1
    btrfs-control    hvc2          loop4   ram0   ram7    sg2     tty14  tty26  tty38  tty5   tty61  vcsa
    bus              hvc3          loop5   ram1   ram8    sg3     tty15  tty27  tty39  tty50  tty62  vcsa1
    console          hvc4          loop6   ram10  ram9    shm     tty16  tty28  tty4   tty51  tty63  vcsu
    cpu_dma_latency  hvc5          loop7   ram11  random  stderr  tty17  tty29  tty40  tty52  tty7   vcsu1
    cuse             hvc6          mapper  ram12  rtc0    stdin   tty18  tty3   tty41  tty53  tty8   vfio
    dm-0             hvc7          mem     ram13  sda     stdout  tty19  tty30  tty42  tty54  tty9   vhost-net
    dri              kmsg          net     ram14  sdb     tty     tty2   tty31  tty43  tty55  ttyS0  vport0p0
    dxg              kvm           null    ram15  sdc     tty0    tty20  tty32  tty44  tty56  ttyS1  vport0p1
    fd               loop-control  nvram   ram2   sdc1    tty1    tty21  tty33  tty45  tty57  ttyS2  vsock
    full             loop0         ppp     ram3   sdc2    tty10   tty22  tty34  tty46  tty58  ttyS3  zero

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# ls -AlF /dev/mapper/
    total 0
    brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   0 Jan 24 20:56 46b8de_vg11-lv15807ccd
    crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 Jan 24 18:50 control

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -o loop,ro /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd
    mount: /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd: failed to setup loop device for /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd.

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -o ro /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd
    mount: /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd: special device /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd does not exist.
    
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -o loop,ro /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd
    mount: /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -o ro /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd
    mount: /mnt/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/46b8de_vg11-lv15807ccd, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/hmnhd
    mount: /mnt/hmnhd: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
    
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/hmnhd
    mount: /mnt/hmnhd: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
    
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -t xfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt/hmnhd
    mount: /mnt/hmnhd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
            
root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount -t xfs /dev/sdc2 /mnt/hmnhd
    mount: /mnt/hmnhd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# mount
    /dev/sdd on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
    rootfs on /init type rootfs (ro,size=4040468k,nr_inodes=1010117)
    none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4040468k,nr_inodes=1010117,mode=755)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
    none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
    tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
    cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/misc type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,misc)
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
    binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
    none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
    none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
    none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
    none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=755)

root@LAPTOP-TIS9JBHH:~# blkid
    /dev/sda: TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/sdb: UUID="75773f41-70f2-41ab-adcb-0fbb216bf538" TYPE="swap"
    /dev/sdd: UUID="3255683f-53a2-4fdf-91cf-b4c1041e2a62" TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/sdc1: UUID="141d2930-efdb-98ee-9e53-3554149220b4" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="9a1654fb-a320-46de-9700-ee2ac28b8142"
    /dev/sdc2: UUID="H1H4u5-Hj57-p0Ja-oHf3-FpNR-4K2e-eFUBfv" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a2f682d1-de59-4b59-b328-3d24a6e5c450"
    /dev/mapper/sdc1: UUID="141d2930-efdb-98ee-9e53-3554149220b4" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="9a1654fb-a320-46de-9700-ee2ac28b8142"
    /dev/mapper/sdc2: UUID="H1H4u5-Hj57-p0Ja-oHf3-FpNR-4K2e-eFUBfv" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a2f682d1-de59-4b59-b328-3d24a6e5c450"
```

All the above commands and outputs have been tried but I have so far failed to understand what I'm missing in order to get this to work.

Note: the drive 'functions' in the NAS, but only the first partition (SDC1) is being utilised in the NAS, the second partition (SDC2) is the not available - no shares, etc.

Comment: Since you can see the volume(s) have you tried mounting the volume(s) and not the disks?  Hint: look at the tools included in lvm2

Comment: You've duplicated PV with kpartx, which LVM might take offense to. So stop using kpartx which isn't necessary here. Run vgchange -a y with -vvv verbose/debug options. Use vgcfgbackup and/or show the metadata in /etc/lvm/backup/yourvg... if its linear in a single segment you can also directly create a readonly loop device with offset and ignore lvm altogether...

Comment: Thanks guys. I've updated the OP to clarify what was done (removing kpartx, and supplying the verbose output of vgchange, etc.

Comment: However, the issue is still persistent. I still cannot mount /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd, or /dev/mapper/46b8de_vg11-lv15807ccd, or dm-0, or any other version of the device. I need some clarification as to why the 'device does not exist' error occurs, and why (if it's related) the loop device is failing - that is assuming it's not just because of the underlying device failing to mount.

Comment: I wanted to provide the output for 'vgchange -ay -vvv' but output is way too long to provide here. I've no idea how to make this available to anyone that might find it relevant. Needles to say, I didn't see anything of particular note in the entire output.

Comment: @frostschutz  Interestingly, after receiving advice, and performing the revised sequence above, I cannot now see/mount/etc SDC1 (the smaller system/apps device) - it's not a primary concern, but it does make me wonder what changed (did I miss something else)?

Comment: not quite sure what is going on with your lvm there, or why the LV wouldn't work in the instance where it is visible; according to your metadata you could try offset 384  (`mount -o ro,loop,offset=$((384*512)) /dev/sdc2 /mnt/somewhere`). this only works for single device, single segment LV

Comment: if there's no filesystem on it, you could try `file -s -L /dev/46b8de_vg11/lv15807ccd ` to check what it is, for example LUKS encrypted. if file says 'data' you can look at raw data with `hexdump -C` ... just to see if you can identify anything. a completely different idea would be to run `testdisk` and see if it finds anything